# I can't execute a SSIS package from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, dll, ssis, ssms

When I want to execute my package from SQL Server, I have this error:

"Failed to initialize Sharepoint Client Runtime. The exception message was: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Runtime. Version=15.0.0.0. Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*************** or one of its dependecies. The system cannot find the file specified.
[image]
The package is well executed in Visual Studion but not from the Server in SSMS. The package is connecting to sharepoint to get a data and save it into a database

Please help me !

I follow the steps here https://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/45645-How-to-use-custom-DLL-in-SSIS-Package.aspx to add the DLL file in the package but I don't have the "References" in my solution.

[image]

Comment: Depending on the .dll/assembly , if it is not a standard one you may have to install it on the server itself as well.

Comment: The "Add Reference" option only adds a reference to the .dll found on your computer running Visual Studio. It doesn't actually bundle it inside the SSIS package, it still needs to be installed on the computer executing your SSIS package. Also... version 15? That's for SharePoint Server 2013. Mainstream support ended for SharePoint Server 2013 back on April 10, 2018 and extended support ended on April 11, 2023. Have you considered upgrading to something supported?